# Centering CSS modal window in a store frame

Tags: css

I am an untalented, low experience dabbler. I have to code some CSS for our NetSuite B2B ecommerce stores from time to time. We create a unique store for each customer.  One of our customers wants a popup window on their store when the page loads. I am able to edit content in 3 separate frames on the splash page for our stores. Otherwise, the store code is not accessible by myself. Looking on the web, I tried a few examples I found. Turns out, I could not use examples that called 3rd party servers. I had to find a purely CSS example, which I did. The CSS code I'm using works almost perfectly. The whole page is greyed out, which I like, and the modal window displays when the page loads. Perfect. The only issue I have is that the modal dialog is left justified. The modal dialog is centered when I run the code by itself, but it is left justified when I run the code in a frame on my store. I want it to be centered horizontally. I've tried 50 different iterations, and the result is always the same. I am hoping you can give me the magic bullet that will finally center the modal dialog. (great... now I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to add the code examples)

HTML

```
<div id="modal-1" class="modal animate-opacity">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-inner">
         <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal-1').style.display='none'" class="modal-close">&times;</span>

         <p><a href="http://www.myfsi.net" target="_blank"><img src="http://4119972-sb1.shop.netsuite.com/c.4119972_SB1/images/Splash/eiab_button.jpg"></a></p>
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 415px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.modal-inner {
        padding: 20px 30px; 
}
.modal-close {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}
.animate-opacity { animation: opac 0.8s }@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out myself
The relevant code was altered thusly

```
.modalz {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 250px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.modalz-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 415px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```